# OneSignal/OneSignal.h' file not found Xcode 10

Tags: objective-c, xcode, onesignal

I try to build this project over and over but it fails every time
is the problem with the signing when I try sign profiles automatically but not manually in one-signal extension I find no profile unlike the main project I can do automatic and manual with no problem but what I care about is run it.
is it a framework problem or signing profile?
look to this picture to see:-
[image: xcode error]

Answer (score 2):

You need to finish set up by importing OneSignal into your project: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup#section-2-import-onesignal-into-your-xcode-project